# Worksheet_Change doesn't fire up when streaming live data

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have read many posts around this topic, however nothing seems to work for my scenario

I would like to `Call Sub` upon cell change (B2) which contains live data feed from external source -`last updated`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Call SubName
    End If
End Sub
```

I went through numerous posts suggesting to check if `Äpplication.EnableEvents = True`, or create function to detect the change ( which does work, however I cannot call sub within function) - with no success.

**`Interestnigly enough, when I click on B2 and press enter - it executes the sub`**

Thanks

Comment: The code looks correct. Did you save the code in the worksheet objects for the sheet you want this to be triggered? If you just save it in a module, it won't work.

Comment: Why do you need `If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then` , just use `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Thx for your response - yes, the code is within the worksheet I am using. Interestnigly enough, when I click on B2 and press enter - it executes the sub.

Comment: Is the live data feed actually changing the contents of the cell, or is it somehow just displaying something (e.g. an image) that makes it look like something is changing?  (I'm not even sure whether that scenario is possible, but there is obviously **something** strange about the data feed.)  Try setting cell C2 (or somewhere) to `=B2` and see whether it is updated.  (If necessary, you could then use the `Change` event to detect a change in C2.)

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K  -  I am certain that the data is updating properly, also I have tried using additional cell ...

Comment: What confuses me is that IT DOES WORK when i click on B2 and press enter.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that B2 has a formula which extracts the data from different worksheet `B2= AnotherSheet!F3`. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` doesn't fire when the change is just the result of a calculation, so a Excel formula, or even a UDF, does not trigger it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say cell **A1** is updated by streaming.  The update will not trigger either:

- Worksheet_SelectionChange
- Worksheet_Change

What you need to do is setup an equation somewhere:

```
=A1
```

When **A1** is refreshed, the formula cell will re-calculate and you can detect it with the Calculate Event.

Comment: Ahhh - the `Calculate` event - of course!  That will also work on the OP's cell B2, because it is just a formula too.

Comment: This is not entirely correct as the OP does not state what they mean by 'streaming'. If cell A1 Value property is changed then it will trigger a  Worksheet_Change event (eg COM writing to Excel). If user selects another cell it will trigger Worksheet_SelectionChange event. If cell A1 is a formula and the formula recalculates then Worksheet_Calculate will fire (eg DDE, or recalc from another Worksheet). Also, it may be the user is monitoring the wrong worksheet to capture the 'real' streaming' event.

Comment: @user3357963  You comments are useful...the benefit of using *Calculate* is that I have never known it to fail...the difficulty with using *Calculate* is the chance of getting false triggers if the worksheet is calculated for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply go

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then SubName
End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K, yes, I was wrong about Worksheet property of Range object. I actually never used it and always use `Parent` property. I edited the code. thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, this one doesnt work either. What confuses me is that when I click on B2 and press enter, it works as expected ( calls the sub)

Comment: Briefly explained- it connects to external source which refreshes every couple of seconds and changes the value

Comment: Ok, I figured out that B2 has a formula which extracts the data from different worksheet B2= AnotherSheet!F3. Any suggestions?